# how can I create entity with 2 element collections?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, playframework

I have an entity object which contains two element collections as such:

```
@Entity
public class Report {

    // Electronic transactions items map
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "catElecItem_key", nullable = false)
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    public Map<Category, ReportItem> catElecItemMap;

    // Branch transactions items map
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "catBranchItem_key", nullable = false)
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    public Map<Category, ReportItem> catBranchItemMap;
}
```

When the tables are being created, a table called **Report_ReportItem** is being generated to do the mapping between **Category** and the mapped **ReportItem**. However this fails as the when trying to save the maps, enther *catElecItem_key* or *catBranchItem_key* will be null.
If I try to annotate with **nullable = true** the table will fail to be created as both keys are  used as part of the primary key definition.

Is it possible to specify for each collection to use a different table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `@CollectionTable` annotation?

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="<custom_map_table_name>")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "catElecItem_key", nullable = false)
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
public Map<Category, ReportItem> catElecItemMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using the **@CollectionTable** annotation. The new class now looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Report {
    // Electronic transactions items map
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "catElecItem_key", nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "TrxReportElecItems", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    public Map<Category, ReportItem> catElecItemMap;

    // Branch transactions items map
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "catBranchItem_key", nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "TrxReportBranchItems", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    public Map<Category, ReportItem> catBranchItemMap;
   ... 
}
```